# How to loop and set inner content of DOM elements in jQuery and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to loop through `divs` and set the content of a `div` inside the outer `div`. I tried this.

Here is the HTML `div`'s I want to loop through and I want to set the content of `div` with class `content-detail` with the value for its attribute data-form data.

```js
//the javascript code I used is this 

$(function($) {
  for (var i of $(".item .content-detail")) {
    var container = document.querySelector($(i)[0]);
    var formData = $(i).attr("data-formdata");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="item">
  <div class="down-div"> </div>
  <div class="detail">
    <h4>Detail</h4>
    <div id="div_" class="content-detail" data-formdata="my Item">

    </div>
    <div class="text-center">
      <button class="btn btn-blue center"> SET !</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <div class="down-div"> </div>
  <div class="detail">
    <h4>Detail</h4>
    <div id="div_" class="content-detail" data-formdata="my Item">

    </div>
    <div class="text-center">
      <button class="btn btn-blue center"> SET !</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But am stuck at this point  `var container = document.querySelector($(i)[0]);` 
I don't know how to get the `jquery` selector of that current div to a variable.

Comment: `$(i)[0]` is a DOM node, not a selector string. You don't need `document.querySelector()`.

Comment: Then what do you suggest, since the idea is to store the container selector in a varable

Comment: Why do you need a selector when you have the element itself? Just do what you want to that element.

Comment: Thanks Bro, I see your point, i never thought of that, it just worked.

Comment: You shouldn't have duplicate `id="div_"`. IDs are supposed to be unique.

Answer (score 1):

This may need some tweaks, but it should be close...

```
$(function ($) {
    $(".item .content-detail").each(function(index, element) {
        element.text($(element).attr("data-formdata"))
    })
});
```

Take a look at the [.each() method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Comment: `.value()` is for inputs. It should be `.text()`

Comment: Good catch @Barmar

Comment: Tanks, What if i want to manipulate other divisions within these div, inside the loop

Comment: You can use the `element` variable, combined with jQuery methods such as `.children()` and `.find()` for something like `$(element).children('p')`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function($) {
    for (var i of $(".item .content-detail")) {
        //var container = document.querySelector($(i)[0]);
        var container = i;
        var formData = $(i).attr("data-formdata");
    }
});
```

I just needed the element

Comment: I've never seen anyone use a `for` loop with a jQuery collection. That's what `.each()` is for.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the content of each DIV, you don't need a `for` loop. The `.text()` method takes a callback function, and it will be called on each element that matches the selector. The returned value is used as the new content.

```
$(".item .content-detail").text(function() {
    return $(this).data("formdata");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
$(function($) {
    $(".item .content-detail").text(function(){
        return $(this).attr("data-formdata");
    })
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you not just use JS like this:

[UPDATED]

```
function test() {
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        var divsSub = divs[i].getElementById("div_").querySelectorAll(".content-detail");;
        for (var iS = 0; iS < divsSub.length; iS++) {                    
            var x = divsSub[iS].getAttribute("data-formdata");
            divsSub[iS].innerHTML = x;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `getElementById` returns a single element, not a collection. There's no `divsSub.length` or `divsSub[iS]`.

Comment: Why not just `divs[i].getElementsByClassName("content-detail")`? Or `document.querySelectorAll(".content-detail")`?

Comment: sorry I forgot to add the query selector: var divsSub = divs[i].getElementById("div_").querySelectorAll(".content-detail");

Comment: There's nothing in the question that says to look for `div_`.